# Menu Toggle is disabled when back to other page in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ionic-framework, menu

I have a menu toggle in my tabs.ts , It's working perfectly, but when returning to the previous page and re-entering to tabs, I click in the menuToggle but it's not working. Why is this happening?, first time working but later not working.
Please Help me.

This is my tabs.ts with my menutoggle :

```html
   <ion-menu [content]="content" >
    
    <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
   
           <img class="avatar" src="assets/img/i2.png">
           <div class="name-user">{{nombre}} {{apellido}}</div>
           <div class="rut-user">{{rut}}</div>

 
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

   <ion-content >
      <ion-list>
     <div class="items-menu">
    <div class="item-menu" (click)="scan()">
          <ion-icon name="md-qr-scanner"></ion-icon>
           <div class="title">Escanear Producto</div>
    </div>


    <div class="item-menu">
       <ion-icon name="md-person"></ion-icon>
          <div class="title">Perfil</div>
    </div>
  <div class="item-menu">
      <ion-icon name="md-settings"></ion-icon>
         <div class="title">Opciones</div>
    </div>
  <div class="item-menu">
      <ion-icon name="md-information-circle"></ion-icon>
         <div class="title">Acerca De</div>
    </div>
  <div class="item-menu"  (click)="cerrarsesion()" >
    <ion-icon name="md-log-out"></ion-icon>
          <div class="title">Cerrar Sesion</div>
    </div>
</div>
     </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
  

   </ion-menu>
   <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="true" ></ion-nav> 


<ion-tabs color="primary">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Carro" tabIcon="cart" tabBadge="2"  tabBadgeStyle="danger"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Perfil" tabIcon="md-person" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This is where I call the menu :

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
     <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu" class="color-icon"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-buttons end>
         <button icon-only ion-button (click)="refreshPage()">
          <ion-icon name="md-refresh" class="color-icon"></ion-icon>
        </button>  
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem i related to the [issue here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10989). 
**First the cause:**
When you navigate to a page, the page html content is supposed to be added within `<ng-component></ng-component>` element, but instead it's added outside it. That gives it a higher z-index over the menu and it's overlay. So, when you toggle the menu, it's actually activated but you just can't see it.

**Now the workaround**
Add the following to your `app.scss` file or anywhere that it can be effective globally:

```
ng-component{
    &.app-root{
        z-index: 10000;
    }
}
```

The value 10,000 of the z-index is so that it will be above the pages that are added outside the ng-component but still below the modals and popovers which are above 10,000.